# Original data with FORM_EVENT?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Is it possible with FORM_EVENT access the original values ​​? Because in form, for adding and editing an item, I entered a date and checks that it is greater than the current date. When editing, I have to check that the date is greater than the current date OR equal to the date initially sent. $Event-> getData() (with addEventListener) returns the data changed :)

Comment: If the form directly manipulates the entity, then the values will already be changed. You could however use a non-mapped field for the new date, and only apply the submitted value if your conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Doctrine UnitOfWork to find the differences that are made to an object.
For this you need access to the EntityManager.

You can get the original object and then check if the date is valid:

```
$uow = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();
$uow->getUnitOfWork()
  ->getOriginalEntityData($object);
```

Or you can get a list of all the properties that have changed:

```
$uow = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();
$changeset = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($object);
```

In most formEventListeners, the changes are already computed, if this is not the case, you can try running `$uow->computeChangeSets();` before getting the entity change set.
But be sure not to run that twice, as it might mess with the changes that are already in there.